# Transfer data from python to labview

Tags: python, labview

i am a beginner for python programming and currently facing huge difficulties in my project. Would like to have some guidance here..

My project is to create a touchscreen interface to control a Labview controlled laser machine. I’m using a surface pro windows system , and with python + kivy module I’m able to create the touchscreeen and generate a series of data when I touch the screen. My aim is to transfer these real-time data as I touch to labview (in ASCII format) so that I can process the data to map and then to control the lasers.

I’m having a great trouble to figure out how to send the data from python on windows surface tablet to labview program. I’m thinking of using TCP/IP but I have no idea how to integrate the simple tcp examples for python to my touchscreen python program ...

Your help is really greatly appreciated ...

Comment: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/python_pal/

Comment: This question is too broad. If you're *'thinking of using TCP/IP'* that implies that the choice of communication interface isn't fixed already, but you're going to modify the LabVIEW program to add it? Is the LabVIEW program running on the same computer as the touchscreen interface? Have you looked for any examples of how to do TCP/IP comms in Python? When you've tried something and hit a problem, ask a specific question showing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a command line interface in LabVIEW to send information from an executing Python script into LabVIEW code. You can use LabVIEW to execute a python script via command line and then receive feedback from that command line interface. You can even have LabVIEW edit the Pyhthon script from within the LabVIEW code and then run the modified Python script.